# Validate a Single line of text column type of list in sharepoint 2010 to accept only numbers?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

How to validate a Single line of text column type of list in sharepoint 2010 to enter accept only numbers?

Please don't tell me to use calculated column , I tried it and it didn't work for me as i want.

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
=ISNUMBER([MyColumn]+0)
```

Comment: I had the same need; to allow only numerals but not show commas.  This works for me except it does allow commas to be entered in a text field.  So, it's close!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what seems to work for me (building on @Rob_Windsor; newlines added for readability):

```
=AND(
  ISNUMBER(Number+0),
  ISERR(FIND(".",Number)),
  ISERR(FIND(",",Number)),
  ISERR(FIND("$",Number)),
  ISERR(FIND("+",Number)),
  ISERR(FIND("-",Number)),
  ISERR(FIND(" ",Number))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through [the available functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/CH010372694.aspx?CTT=97) and I don't see one that will validate whether a text value is a number.

BTW, is there a reason you are not using a Number field instead of a Single line of text?

Comment: Yeah , Number field has comma`s in between. if i take a column number field, instead of 12345 it says 1,23,45.